# Forçar https, www e barra no final da URL com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Estou tentando fazer com que o .htaccess force três coisas. Que sempre acesse com https, www antes do domínio e uma barra no final da URL.

Seguindo sempre esse padrão: https://www.site.com.br/pagina/

Antes eu utilizava apenas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Para redirecionar qualquer URL pro meu index.php. Se eu acessasse www.site.com.br/index.php ele não acessaria diretamente o arquivo, o que me permitia redirecionar para uma página de erro 404.

Pesquisando por aqui cheguei a uma solução que funciona em partes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://www.site.com.br/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Sempre acessa da forma que eu quero. O problema é que, quando eu acesso, por exemplo, wwww.site.com.br/index.php ele permite o acesso direto ao arquivo e com isso não consigo redirecionar para uma página de erro 404.

Tentei remover a extensão do PHP da segunda linha e até mesmo a segunda linha inteira. Mas nesses casos, apesar de ele redirecionar wwww.site.com.br/index.php para wwww.site.com.br/index.php/ como eu gostaria, ele também redireciona qualquer página ( /home/ ou /pagina/, por exemplo ) para /index.php/

Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Este problema já foi tratado inúmeras vezes aqui no site, utilize a pesquisa no topo para localizar a que atenda melhor ao seu caso (é ceerteza que tem várias que atendem, só precisa ver qual você acha mais compreensível para aplicar)

Comment: Bacco, eu até cheguei a pesquisar por aqui mas, foram os casos que encontrei que me fizerem chegar no exemplo que tenho na pergunta. Mas o problema foi juntar as 3 alterações que eu queria sem que resultasse erro. Acabei encontrando uma resposta, vou editar a pergunta com a solução que encontrei com a ajuda de um amigo.

Comment: Darlei, posso estar errado mas não vejo como duplicata. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com alguma ajuda consegui chegar a uma solução para o que eu queria na pergunta. Estou respondendo aqui para o caso de alguém tiver uma necessidade parecida.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Adicionar barra no final da URL, caso não tenha.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Forçar HTTPS e WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.acwebs.com.br/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```